# Asynchronous WCF service, how to return any variable

Tags: silverlight-4.0

```
public int SendServiceCallFromAnotherClass()
{
   client.SendCompleted += new EventHandler<SendCompletedEventArgs>(client_SendCompleted);

   client.SendAsync(clientSettings);

   //i have to return some int here from my service
}

void client_SendCompleted(object sender, SendCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //so here i have to return int variable from my SendServiceCallFromAnotherClass method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a variable from the send completed callback because its signature is defined by the `SendAsync` parameter delegate (`EventHandler<SendCompletedEventArgs>`). What you can do is invoke some other method passing the result of the async operation result which you would find in the `e` parameter.